# Will a separate backend server with Next.js frontend affect the benefits of Next.js (SSR, SEO friendly, etc)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, next.js

Currently I have a backend express server that is used by our mobile apps (iOS and Android). I want to use Next.js for our web app version of the same application for the benefits that its been praised for (SSR, SEO, etc). I don't want to rewrite our current backend api onto the Next.js server. I just want to use Next.js as the frontend while it sends request to our current server (ideally I want to keep the backend code in a single server). I've done a bit of digging and it's entirely possible, however will this render the benefits of Next.js useless so I might as well just use CRA?

I want to have an application that is the most SEO friendly and efficient for users. Wondering which option is the best in this case.

Comment: _"Before deciding to use a custom server, please keep in mind that it should only be used when the integrated router of Next.js can't meet your app requirements. A custom server will remove important performance optimizations, like serverless functions and Automatic Static Optimization."_ --- https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server

Comment: Having a separate API will not affect the benefits you get from Next.js. Why do you think it would?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.